binding the list of table's from the list of dataframe's by selecting the one column from second table
I have a list of data frames in df_list and now i want to rbind them like i want to select all the rows and columns from first data frame and select the any of the one statistics from (Max,Min, Median,Mean).
I have been trying with reduce(merge) and do.call(cbind) but nothing is working.
df_list <- list(
    structure(list(
        ` ` = c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C"),
        N = c("72", "35", "33"),
        Max = c("3.0", "1.0", "2.0"),
        Median = c("8.0", "4.0", "5.0"),
        Mean = c("18.7", "6.9", "14.7"),
        Min = c("20.0", "10.0", "17.5")),
        row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
    structure(list(
        ` ` = c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C"),
        N = c("1", "1", "0"), Max = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"), 
        Median = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"),
        Mean = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"),
        Min = c("3.0", "1.0", "--")),
        row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
)


do.call(cbind, df_list)

the output should be look like below


are you trying to do do.call(cbind, df_list) you need to columnbind not rowbind

i have tried cbind already, mistaken;ly put rbind, but still not giving the desired result

just select the columns you want after cbind ie do.call(cbind, df_list)[c(1:6,8)]

i want to make it dynamic, dont want to hard code it

Given your input, this code achieves exactly the result you say you are targeting
cbind(df_list[[1]],
      setNames(df_list[[2]]["Max"],"Tab2"))

more dynamic with larger example data
df_list <- list(
  structure(list(
    ` ` = c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C"),
    N = c("72", "35", "33"),
    Max = c("3.0", "1.0", "2.0"),
    Median = c("8.0", "4.0", "5.0"),
    Mean = c("18.7", "6.9", "14.7"),
    Min = c("20.0", "10.0", "17.5")),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
  structure(list(
    ` ` = c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C"),
    N = c("1", "1", "0"), Max = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"), 
    Median = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"),
    Mean = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"),
    Min = c("3.0", "1.0", "--")),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
    structure(list(
      ` ` = c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C"),
      N = c("1", "1", "0"), 
      Max = c("4.0", "2.0", "3.0"), 
      Median = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"),
      Mean = c("3.0", "1.0", "--"),
      Min = c("3.0", "1.0", "--")),
      row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
)

do_stat <- function(df_list , stat){
  orig_col <- ncol(df_list[[1]])
  Reduce(f=\(l,r){
    pres_col <- ncol(l)
    tn <- 2 + pres_col - orig_col
    cbind(l,
          setNames(r[stat],paste0("Tab",tn)))
  },
  x=df_list[-1],
  init = df_list[[1]])
  
}

do_stat(df_list,"Max")
 


Or cbind(df_list[[1]], Tab2 = df_list[[2]][["Max"]]) to avoid the setNames

i want to make it dynamic, dont want to hard code it
